# Absolute positioned div won't get height of floated child content

Tags: html, css

I have been banging my head against this for a while, and I'm stumped (and probably missing something obvious).  I have a page with an absolute positioned div, and inside the absolute positioned div, there are two content divs that are floated left.  The height of the left content div is 1200px (based on the content inside of it).  I would like the right div to be the same height as the div to its left, but I cannot get this to occur. The height of the right div is the same as the height of its parent (the absolute positioned div) which is 530px.  If I go up the chain, the body, and html are both 530px as well (they are both said to height: 100%).  I placed a div with clear both at the end of the absolute positioned div containing the two floated divs, and nothing.

This has been driving me crazy.  I'll include a little HTML just to illustrate what's going on:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body> <---- height 100%
<div id="container">
     <div id="header">
     </div>
     <div id="content"> <--- Absolute div, height 100%
          <div id="left-column"><---- float left
          </div>
          <div id="right-column><---- float left
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div> <--- cleared div
     </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put `position:relative` on the container? Where's your CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your real question is

> I would like the right div to be the same height as the div to its left

right?

If so, you can find the solution here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks